# I am trying to create a custom validator in model driven form,is this right way to implement it

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, password-confirmation, angular-custom-validators

while implementing my code i am getting following errors in console

Error: Cannot find control with name: 'password'
    at _throwError (forms.js:1732)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:1640)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:4454)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:4959)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:4909)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9244)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10512)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10474)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11107)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:1106

i tried to create a new form group by grouping password and repassword control,but it does not worked for me.

**add-organization.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-organization',
  templateUrl: './add-organization.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-organization.component.css']
})
export class AddOrganizationComponent implements OnInit {

     myform: FormGroup;
     passwords: FormGroup;
     organizationName: FormControl;
     organizationAddress: FormControl;
     pinCode: FormControl;
     mobileNumber: FormControl;
     organizationType: string[] = ["WholeSale","Retail"];
     businessType: FormControl;
     ownerName: FormControl;
     password: FormControl;
     rePassword: FormControl;
     telephoneNumber: FormControl;
     gstin: FormControl;




  createFormControls() {

     this.organizationName = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
     this.ownerName = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
     this.organizationAddress = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
     this.pinCode = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
     this.mobileNumber = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
     this.telephoneNumber = new FormControl();
     this.businessType = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
     this.gstin = new FormControl("", [Validators.required]);
     this.passwords = new FormGroup({
      password: this.password = new FormControl("",[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8)]),
      repassword: this.rePassword = new FormControl("",[Validators.required])
      },{ validators: this.passwordValidator }
      )
  }

  passwordValidator(fb: FormGroup) {
    let password  = fb.controls.password.value;
    let repass = fb.controls.repassword.value; 
      if (repass !== password) {
        return {
          passwordMatch: {
            passwordMatch: password
          }
        }
      }
    return null;
  } 

  createForm() {
    this.myform = new FormGroup({
    ownerName: this.ownerName,
    organizationName: this.organizationName,
    organizationAddress: this.organizationAddress,
    pinCode: this.pinCode,
    mobileNumber: this.mobileNumber,
    telephoneNumber: this.telephoneNumber,
    businessType: this.businessType,
    gstin: this.gstin,
    }); 
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.myform.valid) {
      console.log("Form Submitted!");
      console.log(this.myform.value);
      this.myform.reset();
    }
  }


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
  }

}
```

**add-organization.html**

```
    <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Set password" type = "password" formControlName="password">
            <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.required">Password is required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="password.errors?.minlength">
                Password must be {{password.errors.minlength.requiredLength}} characters long, we need another {{password.errors.minlength.requiredLength - password.errors.minlength.actualLength}} characters
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input  matInput placeholder="Re-Enter password" type = "password" formControlName="rePassword">
            <mat-error *ngIf="rePassword.errors?.required">Password is required</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="passwords.validators.passwordValidator">not match</mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
```

i expect the out to show error message if both password and rePassword are not same else not

Comment: why do you need this code? `this.password = new FormControl("",[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8)])`. The code looks good otherwise for implementation of a custom validator;

Comment: validators for password

Comment: The error is from the html, which means the password control has some issue; I also noticed that `rePassword` is written as `repassword`

Comment: you are settings password validator for the group.. and setting again for password field ?

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would do this:

```
function passwordValidator() { // wrapper fn
  return (ctrl: AbstractControl) => { // return the function w abstractControl
    const fb = ctrl as FormGroup; //type it
    const passwordCtrl  = fb.get('password'); // get the ctrls
    const repassCtrl = fb.get('repassword'); 
    if (!passwordCtrl || !repassCtrl) // handle errors!
      throw new Error('need password and repass controls');
    if (passwordCtrl.value // make sure forms have values (required error should show in this case, not pass match)
          && repassCtrl.value 
          && repassCtrl.value !== passwordCtrl.value) {
      return {
        passwordMatch: password //redunant
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

define that outside of your component (so it's reusable) then use like:

```
{ validators: [passwordValidator()] }
```

however, your error is really here when you build your group:

```
this.passwords = new FormGroup({
  password: new FormControl("",[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8)]),
  repassword: new FormControl("",[Validators.required])
  },{ validators: [passwordValidator()] }
)
```

you just can't build forms the way you were doing it. you should define your password and repassword variables more like this:

```
get password() { return this.passwords.get('password');
get repassword() { return this.passwords.get('repassword');
```

to get the error to appear as you have it (inside a mat error field) then you need to add this weird thing to your component:

```
parentErrorMatcher = {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl): boolean {
    return control.parent.invalid && control.touched;
  }
};
```

then use it in template on the form field where you want to display the error:

```
<mat-form-field [errorStateMatcher]="parentErrorMatcher">
```

this will cause the error state to reflect the parent instead of the child

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at FormGroup.validator (add-organization.component.ts:8)

Comment: yea there was another error in how your building your form group. in general you should take advantage of formgroups more rather than having 10 different form controls

Comment: where should i call these function

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'passwordValidator' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AddOrganizationComponent.html:47)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives

Comment: `*ngIf="passwords.validators.passwordValidator"` needs to be `*ngIf="passwords.errors?.passwordMatch"`

Comment: now both the fields are getting filles at same time.

Comment: files? not sure what that means

Comment: when i am entering value in password field, the same value is also populated to repassword field also

Comment: You need to post more of your html then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197228/discussion-between-arpit-aggarwal-and-bryan60).

Answer (score 0):

You have created the `Form` twice. Once, with all the controls in `createFormControls()`. Another in `createForm()`. THe createForm does not have the `password` field, thus it does not create a password control, hence the html throws error while creating a formControl with the name `password`.

What you need in the `createForm()` is `patchValue()` to update the value of the controls without changing the structure of the form.

Comment: yes, i fixed that i am getting other issue , please join the disussion

Answer (score 0):

it's only and advise. When you create a formGroup you can use directly

```
this.myform = new FormGroup({
    ownerName: new FormControl('',Validators.Required),
    organizationName: new FormControl('',Validators.Required),
    organizationAddress: new FormControl('',Validators.Required),
    pinCode: new FormControl('',Validators.Required),
    mobileNumber: new FormControl('',Validators.Required),
    telephoneNumber: new FormControl(''),
    businessType: new FormControl('',Validators.Required),
    gstin: new FormControl('',Validators.Required),
    password:new FormGroup({
      password: new FormControl("",[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8)]),
      repassword: this.rePassword = new FormControl("",[Validators.required])
      },{ validators: this.passwordValidator }
      )
    });
```

If you use {validators:this.passwordValidator} your function is declared as

```
passwordValidator(formGroup:FromGroup)
{ 
     ....
}
```

If you use { validators: this.passwordValidator() } //<--see the ()

```
passwordValidator()
{
  return (formGroup:FromGroup)=>
  { 
     ....
  }
}
```

Comment: how to call the function when both the values got entered